# existencia en bd

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hola buenos dias amigos estoy tratando de validar si un registro ya existe en mi bd al momento de tratar de insertar un dato pero no logro hacerlo, porque cuando doy guardar me sale que la funcion o procedimiento tiene demasiados argumentos. estoy manejando todo esto en c# n capas.

EN CAPAS DATOS TENGO ESTO

```
public string LockerExistente(int NLocker)
    {
        string emp = "";
        comando.CommandText = "Select * from locker where NLocker='" + NLocker + "' ";
        try
        {
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NLocker", NLocker);
            comando.Connection = conn.AbrirConexion();
            emp = comando.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            comando.Connection = conn.CerrarConexion();
        }


        return emp;


    }
```

INSERTAR DATOS

```
public void insertLocker(int NLocker, string StatusL)
    {
        comando.Connection = conn.AbrirConexion();
        comando.CommandText = "InsertarLocker";
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NLocker", NLocker);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusL", StatusL);
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        comando.Parameters.Clear();
        comando.Connection = conn.CerrarConexion();
    }
```

CAPA NEGOCIOS

```
public string consultarLocker(string NLocker)
    {
        return obEmployed.LockerExistente(Convert.ToInt32(NLocker));
    }
```

INSERTAR LOCKER

```
public void insertLocker(string NLocker, string Status)
        {
            obEmployed.insertLocker(
                Convert.ToInt32(NLocker), Status);
        }
```

EN CAPA PRESENTACION
SEGUN AQUI YO ESTOY HACIENDO LA COMPROBACION

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            CN_Employed objemploy = new CN_Employed();
           
           if (objemploy.consultarLocker(txtLockerNew.Text) !="")
            {
                
                objemploy.insertLocker(txtLockerNew.Text, comboBox1.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Se Creo Correctamente el Espacio");
                limpiarform();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El Locker ya Existe");
                limpiarform();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se Pudo Crear el Espacio"+ex);
        }
    }
```

espero me puedan guiar

Comment: ¿Y el procedimiento almacenado `InsertarLocker` tiene los parámetros de entrada `@NLocker` y `@StatusL`?

Comment: si, el procedimiento de insertar locker por si solo si funcionaba en el boton, pero al querer hacer la comprobacion hice el select para buscar el numero de locker y ver si existia o no.

Comment: este es mi SP ALTER proc [dbo].[InsertarLocker]
-NLocker int,
-StatusL NVARCHAR(50)
as
insert into locker values (-NLocker,-StatusL);     LOS - SON LOS @

Answer (score 0):

¿Es necesario para tu sistema que al comprobar te traigas todos los registros de tu tabla **locker**? Si no puedes intentar con un count como primer paso:

```
int emp = 0;

comando.CommandText = "Select count(NLocker) from locker where NLocker='" + NLocker + "' ";
```

Después de eso la validación cambiaría a:

```
if (objemploy.consultarLocker(txtLockerNew.Text) = 0)
```

Por otro lado también podrías compartir el código de tu procedimiento almacenado editando la publicación.

Answer (score 0):

Buenos dias ya logre hacer la comprobacion, primero hice pequeñas pruebas con habilitando y deshabilitando un boton para ver si la consulta si estaba mandando un resultado, ya despues de eso procedi a poner en prueba y quedo al cien.

CAPA DATOS

```
public string consultanormallocker(int NLocker)
        {
            string emp = "";
            try
            {
                comando.Connection = conn.AbrirConexion();
                comando.CommandText = "Select NLocker from locker where NLocker='" + NLocker + "'";
                comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                LeerFilas = comando.ExecuteReader();
                if (LeerFilas.Read())
                {
                    return LeerFilas["NLocker"].ToString();


                }
                else
                {
                    return "null";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                comando.Connection = conn.CerrarConexion();
            }
            return emp;


        }
```

CAPA NEGOCIO

```
public string consultarLocker(string NLocker)
        {
            return obEmployed.consultanormallocker(Convert.ToInt32(NLocker));
        }
```

CAPA PRESENTACION

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CN_Employed objemploy = new CN_Employed();
                //textBox1.Text = objemploy.consultarLocker(txtLockerNew.Text);
                if (comboBox1.Text =="")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Indica el Status del Locker");
                    limpiarform();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (objemploy.consultarLocker(txtLockerNew.Text) == txtLockerNew.Text)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("el valor ya existe");
                        limpiarform();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objemploy.insertLocker(txtLockerNew.Text, comboBox1.Text);

                        MessageBox.Show("Se inserto correctamente ");
                        limpiarform();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se Pudo Crear el Espacio" + ex);
            }
        }
```